# Class Handler and parameters

Tags: python, gtk

I'm opting for the handler class alternative to connect to the signs of my glade project.

Example:

XML Galde

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
<object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<signal name="delete-event" handler="onDeleteWindow" swapped="no"/>
<child>
<object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
<property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
<property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">True</property>
<property name="receives_default">True</property>
<property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
<signal name="pressed" handler="onButtonPressed" swapped="no"/>
</object>
</child>
</object>
</interface>
```

Python code

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def onButtonPressed(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("builder_example.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

What if I need to pass parameters to the methods? For example, in the code below.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def onButtonPressed(self, button, any_widget):
        print("Hello World!", type(any_widget))


label = Gtk.Label() #HOW TO PASS THIS WIDGET TO THE onButtonPressed METHOD?

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("builder_example.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

I can solve using dictionary. But I do not know how to do this using handler class.

Comment: In C, the [second parameter to `connect_signals()` is the last parameter of each signal handler](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals). I do not know if this holds true in Python or not. Alternatively, could you make `label` an instance variable of `Handler`, create a new `Handler`, assign that instance variable, and then pass the `Handler` into `connect_signals()`?

Comment: In a larger, more complex project, this solution is not very elegant.
The Handler class must contain only the manipulation methods. He can not have widget objects.